# Trying to Turn Multiple Cylinders(parts) into a curve

Tags: mesh, conversion

I have an obj file of some roller coaster track, specifically the rails by themselves. It is not well-optimized and is made up of multiple cylinder models all lined up one after another to create the rails(yes, not good)

I've been trying to find a way to convert this into a curve or something similar in Blender so it can be optimized.

I've been using Blender for a while but there is still a lot I don't know. I can't seem to figure this out. If someone has any idea on how I could accomplish this I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Edit: here is a picture of the mesh
[image]

Cylinders are cut into 4ths:
[image]

Comment: Some thing like a roller coaster track can be made procedurally using geometry nodes. Are you comfortable with those?

Comment: Show  picture of the mesh. It's hard to tell what you are working with and the easiest solution otherwise. If it's that bad the easiest would probably be to just make a cuve and place it manually to overlap the cylinders

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I would prefer not to have to recreate the mesh by hand. I feel like each piece is close enough to another that there might be a good way to just convert it. I have not used geometry nodes in Blender before, I will look into that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like that select one of the vertices in the center of the end faces, then shift+G->Amount of connecting edges. This should select all the center vertices.
[image]
With all of them selected, hit ctrl+X to dissolve them so that the circles at the end of each cylinder become a single face.
Then select one of those faces and Shift+G -> Polygon sides. This will select all the round faces.
[image]
Then, with the pivot point set to individual origins, scale them to 0. Then merge the vertices by distance. This Should leave you with a single line of vertices
[image]

You can give it a subdivision modifier to make it smoother and use a skin modifier and subdivision to get a cylindrical rail. Or you can convert it into a curve and use another curve as the profile

Comment: This is so close! It seems the cylinders are made up of 4 pieces each(they are quartered at the rounded face, like how a pie is cut) and after dissolving them I'm not left with one round face but 4 quarter faces, so I'm not able to get the end result you did. I'll add a screenshot above.

Comment: With the quarter faces selected like that you should be able to merge the vertices by distance. This should at least merge the center vertices on all the faces. That will treat them like a single object then that you can scale to 0 on individual origins to get the same end result

Comment: Yes, you are correct! this is awesome thank you so much!!